# How do I import data from 6 Excel Workbooks into one on a daily basis?

Tags: windows, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I'm needing to be able to pull data from 6 individual Excel Workbooks that are all formatted the same, first line being the same header across all six and then the data starting row 2 going down being formatted the same across all 6.

We are basically using this for small mailings at work and as such employees paste addresses with names in a "post" Excel workbook, always on the first sheet always starting with the 2nd row.

I have a master "post" workbook, and at the moment I manually have to go into everyone else's and cut their labels and put them in the master one and then print.

How would I automate the cutting of post labels (basically data written left to right across a couple of columns) and pasting it into the master Excel sheet? (the data needs to be deleted from the 6 workbooks).

I have tried all help info I could find and searched a lot, but I just can't work this out.

I don't want the headers posted into the master file, the master file already has the same headers for sorting.

Thanks. (Office 2007 or 2013 instructions will be fine.)

Comment: I would suggest that a split database would be the best solution you could seek in this situation which would provide you with a form interface on the front end for each of your employees, while capturing your data in the back-end.  In the long run, it will be much less daily work than the method you currently describe using excel.

Comment: Like @OSol1tair3 says, a database could do it. Take a look at Access.

Comment: Right tool for the right job, I would be doing this in a database

Comment: *Suggestion*: share a workbook on a network location so everyone can add their data to that. Then you can open it, print your labels and clear the content for them to be able to add more.  This keeps it in one file.

Comment: Hey CharileRB, your suggestiong doesn't work because only one user at a time could add labels, and that's not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how strict the rules/how competent your colleagues are the solutions vary from:

- shared workbook: everyone understands everything and is trusted with
  the data.
- split database: everyone gets an input form and you all
  work from the same dataset; they are not trusted with the data but
  are all competent enough to use it comfortably
- separate databases: a macro runs an append query from all the diasporic
  datasets to the master table and then runs a delete query   the master
- Excel file opening the subordinate ones (in a looping fashion), copying the
  data, then deleting, then saving on close.
  How much free time do you
  have?

Comment: Well, at the moment, everyone has their own and one has to combine it into one. With a shared workbook it doesn't really work because only one could add to it at one time unless we do it with Office Online which we don't really want to do.

I'm basically looking for whatever is the easiest solution.

Comment: A [shared workbook](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/share-workbooks.html) on a shared drive is available to virtually infinite users (I think 20 at the same time). Make sure people save frequently, autosave goes I think every 5 minutes.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ended up doing.

It doesn't always work perfectly though, for example, if someone types a whole address in rather than copy paste it, it pushes everyone else's down a couple of rows because we've set people to start entering labels commencing at a certain row.

If only people could just continuously add labels to this shared Excel file even though overwriting, that would be fab.

It would be nice to just have it keep both versions all the time, as in, a continuous adding of labels for example.

Answer (score 0):

Open a new workbook, press ALT+F11.

Add a new module, and paste the following vba code:

```
Sub mergexlfiles()
Dim actwb As Workbook

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim DestRow As Long

Dim mergeObj As Object, dirObj As Object, filesObj As Object, everyObj As Object
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set mergeObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set dirObj = mergeObj.Getfolder("C:\folder\") 'update folder path
Set filesObj = dirObj.Files
For Each everyObj In filesObj
Set actwb = Workbooks.Open(everyObj)

LastRow = actwb.Worksheets(1).Cells.Find(What:="*", _
             After:=actwb.Worksheets(1).Cells.Range("A1"), _
             SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
             LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
             SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row

Range("A2:S" & LastRow).Copy 'amend "S" to last column letter in source files

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate

Range("A" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count).Offset(1, 0).Value = actwb.Name
Range("B" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial

Application.CutCopyMode = False
actwb.Close
Next
End Sub
```

Be sure to update the commented sections, and run the macro.

The script will open each file within the folder you specified in turn, and paste the the contents into a new workbook.

When the screen updates, you'll have a single excel sheet with all the contents combined.

Hope that helps.

(i adapted a some vba i found elsewhere, apologies i'm unsure of original source.)

Comment: Isn't it possible for this command to always paste the contents into the same workbook and not create a new one every time? We also have some specific rows we want to keep for sorting and cleanup before we print. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can import data into your master workbook from any number of other workbooks by using data connections in excel. I had done this along time ago and it worked out very well. This MS office webpage explains how to set it up. You can even place the data in you master in different cell ranges as to track whose mailings are going out.

[Connect data in another workbook to your workbook](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Connect-data-in-another-workbook-to-your-workbook-3a557ddb-70f3-400b-b48c-0c86ce62b4f5)

Haven't figured out how you can clear the individual workbooks of data that you have imported already but this may be a good start.

Comment: I have already found that article and tried playing with data connections but I just can't get it to work. It keeps on pasting headers as well instead of just the data, and as such, it's useless to me...